# Typescript type annotation for object property on initialisation

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to do a type annotation for a specific property when initialising an object in Typescript?

In my case I have a template literal type

```
type ID = `book#${string}`;
```

and I want to make sure that when I create an object (which needs to be of type Record<string, any>, so I cannot enforce type there):

```
const a = {
  id: `book#abc` # Should be fine
}
```

that there is a lint / compile time error if I write for example

```
const a = {
  id: `car#abc` # Should NOT be fine
}
```

I am looking for something along the lines of

```
const a = {
  id: `book#abc` as ID
}
```

but that would just assume (assert?) that the id is correct.

The only solution I have found is to create a function

```
function asId(x: ID): ID {
  return x;
}
```

which I don't find very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer *might* violate this constraint

> ...which needs to be of type `Record<string, any>`, so I cannot enforce type there...

but I don't think so (details below).

You could define a `WithID` type like this:

```typescript
type WithID = {id: ID} & Record<string, any>;
```

That enforces the requirement on `id` while allowing other properties:

```typescript
const a: WithID = {
    id: `book#abc`,  // Works
    whatever: 42,
};
const b: WithID = {
    id: `car#abc`,  // Type error
    whatever: 42,
};
```

The reason I don't think it violates the constraint I quoted above is that `a` and `b` can be used anywhere a `Record<string, any>` can be used. Example:

```typescript
function usageExample(o: Record<string, any>) {
    console.log(o);
}
usageExample(a); // Works

// And

const c: Record<string, any> = a; // Works
```

So the `id` being "tighter" really just applies to the object literal you're assigning.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgIlAvFABgIwPYYNYGIAkA3gM7ABOAlgHYDmAvigNwCwAUKJFAOoXAAW8JFEIUAJgC5YcOlABkUAEoQAxhjKiAPKUq0ANFACGVEAD4WrNqqqlDknv0HJCbKK6hjJ6LHgNplKfSgAeiDuNWxiFzcAdz4DYAgANwgySQAWACZdNjpzKxs0O14BBCco1w9UZQMyXF9-QJCoABVwaBSyNXKoWPiklPSsnPM2ADMAVyplYAoMKihx4gMaCABRAA8DAFswABsIAAoMSSVVdS1yahp9I1MASmFu-Ix9gDpdjBoju-M6NkXlmtNjt9gcDD9gqEuOFIhZWE0AIJUURsSxzGzKE4qNSabRXG7GExCAyMSFhMgRNhAA)

Comment: It is not what I was hoping for, but I think I will have to do something similar to this. Big thanks!